# Numerically find approximating matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization

Given $n$ trace-free hermitian mutually orthonormal matrices $M_1,...,M_n \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d}$ and a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d}.$

I want to solve the problem of finding the optimal $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\left\lVert A - \sum_{i=1}^{n } a_i M_i \right\rVert$ is minimal under the constraint that $\langle \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iM_i x,x \rangle \ge -1 $ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^d.$

Apparently, this problem is convex, but I do not see how to implement the condition $\langle \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iM_i x,x \rangle \ge -1 $ (diagonalising and checking eigenvalues in each step seems unreasonable) in an effective algorithm. Does anybody know how these things can be done?

Comment: Your constraint is essentially a semidefinite program with $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iM_i + I \succeq 0$$ which is an LMI

Comment: @percusse sorry what does LMI stand for? I understand that you can reformulate this in terms of a semidefinite problem, as you stated correctly, but I do not see how this is equivalent to a semidefinite program as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming#Duality_theory

Comment: @percusse okay, I found LMI=linear matrix inequality. However, I did not find a method for this case so far.

Comment: @percusse For it to be an LMI, shouldn't the RHS be $-\|\mathrm x\|_2^2$?

Comment: @Marcel What matrix norm are you using in the objective function?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Ah yes. My mistake. Read too fast.

Comment: @percusse Also, in an LMI, the matrices and the variables are real.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No hermitian is fine. These are traceless.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Frobenius

Answer (score 1):

Let $B(a) = - \sum_i a_i M_i$. The condition amounts to
$$ -1 \le \min_{x :\; \|x\|_2 = 1}\langle -B(a)x ,x \rangle = - \max_{x :\; \|x\|_2 = 1}\langle B(a) x ,x \rangle = -\lambda_{\max}(B(a)).
$$
That is the condition is $\lambda_\max(B(a)) \le 1$. I am going to assume that it is benign to also add the condition $\lambda_\max(B(-a)) \le 1$ (maybe this can be argued formally). The the two conditions amount to $\|B(a)\|_{op} \le 1$ for the operator 2-norm. The problem can be cast as an SDP:
\begin{align}
  \min \| A - B(a)\| \quad \text{subject to} \\
  \begin{pmatrix}
    I & B(a) \\
    B^*(a) & I
  \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0  
\end{align}